# get image source of current slide in cycle2 slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I'm trying to get the source of the current image in an installation of Cycle2 to pass to an addThis photo sharing script

here is what I have been able to figure out from the Cycle2 API:

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-after', function (e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    var imgSrc = $(outgoingSlideEl).attr('src');
});
```

If I'm missing anything, please advise.

Comment: the options within the function() are the default ones.
Where I'm most uncertain, is that do I need to append those values for incoming and outgoing slides as classes?

Comment: ok both of your jsfiddles make sense. The slideshow isnt structured with list though, its a set of div containers specified within a php loop. Would it make sense to append the "outgoingSlideEl" as a class to the div?


here's the contents of the loop w/
some additional code


  $sldshw .="<div class='slide heroSlider slide".$i."'><img src='".$property['image']."' title='".$property['name']."' /><div class='heroImageText'>".$property['heroText']."</div></div>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `outgoingSlideEl` is an `list element` like `li`

Then you should use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find) to find your `image src` like,

```
var imgSrc = $(outgoingSlideEl).find('img').attr('src');
```

**Full Code**

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-after', function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl,
                                                  incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    var imgSrc = $(outgoingSlideEl).find('img').attr('src');
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/DHegy/)

Comment: we have given almost same answer on the same time :))

Answer (score 0):

can you give a try to below code..i hope it works

```
var imgSrc = $(outgoingSlideEl).find('img').attr('src');
```

Demo :-

http://jsfiddle.net/3vjgJ/42/